# Getting Total Cost Grouped by User

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, pivot

I've been struggling with this query for two days now. I've got a **user** table with some values which has a relation with an **order** table (user can have multiple orders). This table has a relation with **order_item** (order can have multiple orderItems). Order_Item has a relation with **invoice** (order_item can have multiple invoices.

The branch and shop have a one-on-one relation with the user.

Here are the most important values of all the tables:

```
user:
-userId (int)

order
-orderId (int)
-userId (int)
-inserted (date)

order_item
-orderItemId (int)
-orderId (int)

invoice
-invoiceId (int)
-orderItemId (int)
-cost (double)
```

The foreign keys are self-explanatory here. User->Order->OrderItem->Invoice.
What I need is a query in which each row in the result represents a user with two columns representing the total sales (sum of costs) in 2014 and 2015.

So what it has to do is show each user in a row with some info from the user table (company name, e-mail etc etc) and two columns with the total costs of 2014 and one of 2015 based on the order.inserted date value.

An example would be:

**Name:  | E-Mail          | 2014 Cost | 2015 Cost**

Google | info@google.com | €50.000   | €45.000

Now I've gotten so far that I've got a result for the first sum (showing all users regardless of cost), only when I join a second time (to calculate the 2015 cost) my previous sum costs get completely screwed up.

I tried some select queries within joins but I couldnt get any query to work. It's not like I'm a complete beginner in SQL but this is too complex for me to figure out this exact moment.

This is the query I use to get the 2014 result (and as soon as I add a second join for 2015 it gets screwed up):

```
SELECT t.userId, SUM(i.cost),
t.companyName, t.email,
t.website, t.tel, t.priority,
b.name AS Branch, s.name AS `Shop Name` 
FROM `user` AS t
LEFT JOIN branch AS b ON b.branchId = t.branchId
LEFT JOIN shop AS s ON s.shopId = t.shopId
LEFT JOIN `order` AS o ON (o.userId = t.userId AND YEAR(o.inserted) = 2014) 
LEFT JOIN order_item AS oi ON oi.orderId = o.orderId
LEFT JOIN invoice AS i ON i.orderItemId = oi.orderItemId 
GROUP BY t.userId
```

I really hope somebody can help me with this. (I'm using mySQL/innoDB in Navicat 8).

Comment: Would the `branch` and `shop` tables ever produce multiple records per `userId`, or is that a one-to-one relationship? It matters for the `GROUP BY`'s application.

Comment: The branch and shop references have a one-on-one relation with user. Thanks for pointing it out, adding it to the question.

Comment: FYI, this business of putting 2014 and 2015 in separate columns is called a "pivot" in the jargon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, this is a form of *pivot table* you are trying to produce. Instead of joining and testing the year conditions in the joins' `ON` clauses, you may place the condition directly inside `SUM()` aggregates like:

```
-- If the year matches, add the cost value into the sum
-- Otherwise, add zero
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.inserted) = 2014 THEN i.cost ELSE 0 END) AS `2014 Cost`
```

This eliminates the need for those extra joins.  When applying the `GROUP BY`, it should include all columns which could potentially be different per group.  MySQL allows you to omit columns in `SELECT` from `GROUP BY` where most other RDBMS would result in a query compile error.

```
SELECT 
  t.userId,
  -- Apply the aggregate SUM() conditionally for each year
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.inserted) = 2014 THEN i.cost ELSE 0 END) AS `2014 Cost`
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.inserted) = 2015 THEN i.cost ELSE 0 END) AS `2015 Cost`
  t.companyName,
  t.email,
  t.website,
  t.tel,
  t.priority,
  b.name AS Branch,
  s.name AS `Shop Name` 
FROM 
  `user` AS t 
  LEFT JOIN branch AS b ON b.branchId = t.branchId
  LEFT JOIN shop AS s ON s.shopId = t.shopId
  LEFT JOIN `order` AS o ON (o.userId = t.userId) 
  LEFT JOIN order_item AS oi ON oi.orderId = o.orderId
  LEFT JOIN invoice AS i ON i.orderItemId = oi.orderItemId 
GROUP BY 
  t.userId,
  -- Adding remaining SELECT fields
  -- though MySQL will allow these to be omitted
  -- without breaking this particular query
  t.companyName,
  t.email,
  t.website,
  t.tel,
  t.priority,
  Branch,
  `Shop Name`
```

Comment: You could also join to order table twice with addition qualifier on year -- this might be faster than case on some systems depending on indexes etc.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Thanks for the tips and the answer, really helped me out!

Comment: @Hogan: Double join is a bad practice for this kind of problems, adding a simple date filter should be better: "o.inserted between <<full date range>>" works much better.

Comment: @PeterKrassoi - I would be careful using a term like bad practice - such a technique is clearly not "bad practice".  It might not be the fastest solution, but it is in many cases but a standard SQL technique.  It really depends a lot on the data and the database structure which technique is best.  Knowing all the techniques and applying the best one is good practice.